# Updating Samba on CentOS 5.4

Tags: linux, centos, samba

We have a box running CentOS 5.4, with Samba 3.0.33-3.14.el5 on it. And as per https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/386924/my-smb-shares-wont-mount-under-catalina-whats-wrong, I've just discovered that MacOS Catalina won't connect to SMB1, and so I 
need to update Samba to at least 3.5, and preferably to a supported 
version.

Does anybody know of any reason why the latest Samba wouldn't work on that 
version of CentOS?

It's been a long time since I did any updating on that box. Can somebody 
point me in the direction of the easiest way to update the Samba server?

---

I tried "yum update samba" and got

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Determining fastest mirrors
YumRepo Error: All mirror URLs are not using ftp, http[s] or file.
 Eg. Invalid release/repo/arch combination/
removing mirrorlist with no valid mirrors: /var/cache/yum/extras/mirrorlist.txt
Error: Cannot find a valid baseurl for repo: extras
```

Based on https://www.faqforge.com/linux/distributions/centos/updating-samba-on-centos-5/, I then tried:

```
cd /etc/yum.repos.d
wget http://ftp.sernet.de/pub/samba/3.5/centos/5/sernet-samba.repo
```

and got:

```
--2020-04-02 08:30:50--  http://ftp.sernet.de/pub/samba/3.5/centos/5/sernet-samba.repo
Resolving ftp.sernet.de... 185.199.217.240, 2a0a:a3c0:0:d2eb::1
Connecting to ftp.sernet.de|185.199.217.240|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 301 Moved Permanently
Location: https://samba.plus/ [following]
--2020-04-02 08:30:51--  https://samba.plus/
Resolving samba.plus... 185.199.218.23, 2a0a:a3c0:0:d2d2::1
Connecting to samba.plus|185.199.218.23|:443... connected.
Unable to establish SSL connection.
```

Comment: CentOS 5.4 was released in Oct 2009, so you may well find that the packages are no longer available... have you tried updating with `yum`?

Comment: Absolutely nothing wrong with asking here, but you may find an answer more quickly in the future by using http://unix.stackexchange.com . You can search there for an answer to this issue, but please don't double-post on both sites.

Answer (score 0):

CERN mirror Vault does not require TLS 1.2 so still works with older CentOS

http://linuxsoft.cern.ch/centos-vault/

https://www.mark-gilbert.co.uk/fixing-yum-repos-on-centos-6-now-its-eol/

Answer (score 0):

Download the samba repo :

```
<code>cd /etc/yum.repos.d/
wget http://ftp.sernet.de/pub/samba/3.5/centos/5/sernet-samba.repo</code>
```

[...] update samba:

```
<code>yum update samba</code>
```

Probably, you will need winbind too:

```
<code>yum install samba3-winbind samba3-utils</code>
```

Check the rpm version:

```
<code>rpm -qa | grep samba</code>
```

Restart Samba:

```
<code>/etc/init.d/smb restart</code>
```

SOURCE: [Updating Samba on CentOS 5](https://www.faqforge.com/linux/distributions/centos/updating-samba-on-centos-5/)

Comment: `unable to resolve host address 'ftp.sernet.de'`